# Getting latLng from google maps api to store that in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, proximity

I am using Postgres with postGIS extension.  I just installed everything a while ago.

I'm looking at the documentation (it is really difficult for beginners in my opinion - is there any other tutorial or something you recommend?) and it seems I have to create a point from my lat and long, and that in a geospatial database it is (x,y) so I have to flip my lat and long to long, lat.

So, I'm creating markers in my front end application, but I'm confused as to how I can store them in my database.

Here's an example of the marker data that my web Api (using node and a postgres client) is sending over to Postgres (I am able to insert it into my table, so I have some test data):

```
{
  "lat": 40.7128,
  "lng": 74.0059,
  "title": "Big Apple",
  "description": "New York City, NY, USA.  The best city in the world!",
  "createdBy": 33823,
  "type": 4
}
```

My goal with using postGIS is to be able to do something like this:

I am using my app and I have my current location.  Find stuff that's within 1 mile of me.

Is there any guidance you can provide to me on how to get started towards that?

From the documentation, I need to create a point.  But then it delves into using a type of coordinate system to use.  At this point I have no idea what anything means.  I am trying to put together a proof of concept for an idea I've had for a while, but this is the biggest roadblock I've hit.

Comment: Perhaps a code snippet of what you've tried so far would be helpful.

Comment: this location is in the Western hemisphere, where longitudes are negative

Answer (score 1):

Coordinate reference systems have to do with [map projection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection). In the GIS world there are many [reference systems](http://spatialreference.org/) and postgis needs to know what you're using.

Since your coordinates are in lat/lon you can use [wgs84](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) which has an epsg reference number of 4324. Just pass 4324 as the final argument in your geometry insert.

The column definition could be something like:

```
St_geomfromtext( 'POINT:(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')' , 4324)
```

Then once you've populated your database with points and their attributes you can use [st_dwithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to get the points within the user's area:

```
Select... From... Where st_dwithin(my.geometry, poi.geometry, 1609)
```

Comment: THanks Jesse!  Just a quick question.  Can you please explain the 1609 value in the Select query?  I understand now that 4324 would be my reference system since I am using lat/long.  However, I am confused about the 1609.  Thank you!

Comment: 1609 meters are approximately one mile.

Comment: Ah ok.  So I had to change my column to `geography` and now I can query by meters.  With `geometry` it uses radians according to the documentation perhaps that is why it was not working.  I am not good at math so I will hope this is suitable :D